# Possible to use same git checkout for multiple users?

Tags: git

I'd like my team to be able to individually use the same checked out repo on our server to pull updates. Would it be possible to have a copy of the repo where multiple individual users would be able to make pull/merge requests from their own accounts?

Comment: yeah that tag shouldn't have been there =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan that worked for me was (since this is an already checked-out repo) to run `git config core.sharedRepository true` to set the repo as a shared repo.  I then went through and made sure all the git files were `chmod` to 664, and all of the folders were `chmod` to 775, to allow group-writability for git to work correctly between users.  Then, simply have each user set up their own user-level git config for email address, name, etc in their home folder. 
 **NOTE:** The world-readability, and ownership of certain files in the repo still needed to be maintained, as in this particular case, the repo in question was being served by our dev server (Apache).
 Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

First, I suggest reading [Distributed Workflows chapter](http://progit.org/book/ch5-1.html) from the Pro Git book and first make sure you understand the workflow which is best suited for your team.

I'm on a small team and we use much of the same setup as you are suggesting.  There is a repo which all work is eventually pulled into.  There are multiple users with seperate unix accounts pull, merge, and push their own branches to.

Here are the basic steps:

- Make sure everyone's login is in the same group on the machine, such
  as `project_dev`.
- `chown -R :project_dev <git_location>` to make sure the git repo
  which is accessabile by everyone's account.
- After that you make sure the git repo is configured appropriately
  with: `git repo-config core.sharedRepository true` This lets everyone push to the repo without causing a potential permission conflict with the pushed objects.

After you have taken care of those things, users can use sftp or local file uri's to work with that repo with their own accounts.  There are much more advanced ways to handle account permissions with git, but this is one of the simplest.  Check out the Pro Git book and google for some other alternatives, [Gitolite](http://progit.org/book/ch4-8.html) is one of the more advanced options.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll definitely look into that book.

Answer (score 0):

They could all be authenticated using the same user and then simply change the author for the commit.

From the man page for [git commit](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-commit):

```
--author=<author>
Override the author name used in the commit. 
You can use the standard A U Thor <author@example.com [1] > format. 
Otherwise, an existing commit that matches the given string and its author name is used.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is rather short: **yes**.

This is the basis on how **forks** work, for example on GitHub. They are just separate repositories and each developer can have own repository, there is no limitation regarding that. And there can be one (or more, if anyone wishes) repository with read-only access for some (or all) developers, working as production repository, where all changes need to be pulled by senior developer (or other appropriate person).

Also such forks may be added as so called "remotes" (remote repositories) to the local ones, and read-only ones can be used for pulling changes on a daily basis, where read-write ones should be used for pushing / saving changes. **Pull requests** can be made using various software - eg. GitHub has separate feature for it. **Pull request** in general is a way to ask for pulling your changes into repository to which you have no "write" permission. People with "write" permission may accept it, comment on it, change it or reject it etc., giving you more control over what happens with such code base.

The clue here is that **Git is a distributed version control system** and you can have multiple repositories, organize them in a manner you want. Some of the repositories can be read-write repositories for your developers, some can be read-only ones.

There is also a concept mentioned by @BeRecursive: the user that makes a commit is not necessarily the one that uploads the changes to the repository. But this is absolutely different idea and it can be easily fooled, thus I think you should not rely on such method.